# NoClassDefFoundError when hudson runs a maven project

Tags: maven, hudson

I have a project for running tests. It's a maven project which uses Selenium. It runs correctly when launched locally, but from the Hudson platform, it throws NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Parsing POMs
[elsevier-selenium] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java" -Xmx1024m -cp E:\hudson\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven-agent-1.353.jar;E:\maven\boot\classworlds-1.1.jar hudson.maven.agent.Main E:\maven E:\hudson\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-1.353.jar E:\hudson\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven-interceptor-1.353.jar 1753 E:\hudson\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven2.1-interceptor-1.2.jar
<===[HUDSON REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f E:\hudson\jobs\tests-selenium\workspace\elsevier-selenium\pom.xml integration-test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building selenium-elsevier
[INFO]    task-segment: [integration-test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default}]
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to E:\hudson\jobs\tests-selenium\workspace\elsevier-selenium\target\test-classes
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] [failsafe:integration-test {execution: default}]
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: E:\hudson\jobs\tests-selenium\workspace\elsevier-selenium\target\failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running fr.elsevier.tests.disponibilite.SearchTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.203 sec <<< FAILURE!
fr.elsevier.tests.disponibilite.SearchTest  Time elapsed: 0.203 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class fr.elsevier.tests.BaseSelenium
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SmartStackTraceParser.getClass(SmartStackTraceParser.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SmartStackTraceParser.<init>(SmartStackTraceParser.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4StackTraceWriter.smartTrimmedStackTrace(JUnit4StackTraceWriter.java:72)
    [...]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
```

SearchTest extends BaseSelenium.

Which means it cannot even find a class in my source folder. The project structure is like this:

```
src/
  fr.elsevier.tests/
    disponibilite/
      SearchTest.java
    BaseSelenium.java
pom.xml
```

**Why does the build generates these NoClassDefFoundErrors and how to fix it?**

Comment: Try using -e or -X command line argument in local and hudson build. Then try to compare the classpath of the java processes launched.

Comment: Thanks @SSR , with the -X options, I could see the maven profiles were badly configured, which caused an exception during the initialisation of static variables of BaseSelenium. The classpath was ok. Too bad the exception printed is so unintuitive: "NoClassDefFoundError" when the class was actually found but failed to initialize.

Comment: Added the same as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using -e or -X command line argument in local and hudson build. Then try to compare the classpath of the java processes launched.

You can then actually figure out which part of maven lifecycle threw the exception with better stacktrace.